# Importing a `.jpeg`, `.prj` and `.wld` triplet as a raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a couple `.jpeg` files of few hundred megabytes each along their `.prj` projections and `.wld` world files – i.e. some georeferenced raster from what I read — and wish to import them for use with [`osmand`](https://osmand.net/) as overlays.

I'm quite a newbie in this field and have no idea of the steps to follow, however I'm guessing that a good first step is to properly import these files as georeferenced raster layers in `QGIS 3.12`.

What is the proper way to import a `.jpeg`, `.prj` and `.wld` triplet as a raster layer in QGIS?

Comment: So big JPEG is a poor selection as a GIS format. Convert it into a tiled, JPEG compressed GeoTIFF and it will perform much better in QGIS.

Comment: I do agree, it seems that most errors I get from tools with these files are caused by floating-point errors due to the span they covers. However, I have no choice, these files are almost a decade old and sourced from a third-party, sadly :/

Comment: Convertion is simple. `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=jpeg -co photometric=YCBCR input.jpeg output.tif` should yield much better behaving images. Even better if you let QGIS write overviews for you of if you create them yourself with gdaladdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS will pick up the georeferencing from the world file if it has the same naming convention:

File:

```
MyRaster.jpeg
```

World file:

```
MyRaster.jpw
```

PRJ:

```
MyRaster.prj
```

Not sure if QGIS picks up the projection for Rasters from a prj file, but if not you can set the projection manually after it is importer. Right click on the layer> Properties...> Source> Geometry and Coordinate Reference System.

Comment: I'm getting `Invalid Projection` in the layer's source properties, however by looking inside the `.prj` file I was able to set the proper CRS. Thank you!

Comment: World file named as .wld should be OK. Did you have problem with it?

Comment: Just tried it with a name ending with `.wld` and it works flawlessly. I still had to set the projection by hand.