# Export a georeferenced `QGIS` raster for use as `OSMAnd` overlay?

Tags: qgis, osmand

I have a couple `.jpeg` files of few hundred megabytes each along their `.prj` projections and `.wld` world files – i.e. some georeferenced raster from what I read — and wish to import them for use with [`OSMAnd`](https://osmand.net/) as overlays. This is a follow-up of a previous question I asked:

- [How to import a `.jpeg`, `.prj` and `.wld` triplet as a raster layer in `qgis`?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352332/how-to-import-a-jpeg-prj-and-wld-triplet-as-a-raster-layer-in-qgis)

**I now have a proper georeferenced raster** imported into `qgis` and it seems that I can export (via `Save As` with a right-click on the layer) tiles as georeferenced `.tiff` but not `.mbtiles` as I get a `cannot find min and max_zoom_level`. Note that I tried to pick a `EPSG:3857` projection for `.mbtiles` as using the `EPSG:4326` was getting me an error.

**I'm wondering how to import them inside `OSMAnd`**. I've found that `OSMAnd` use `.obf` files for offline maps and/or may also use a `.sqlite` database. It seems that I may have to do a [conversion](https://github.com/tarwirdur/mbtiles2osmand) but I'm not sure how to use the output file, nor how to generate an `.obf` file.

Thus, to sum up:

- **How to export a `qgis` raster layer for use as an overlay or underlay inside `osmand`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully exported the raster to `OSMAnd` as following:

1. Right-click on the layer, `Export > Save As`.
2. Configure first `Rendered Image`, then pick `GeoTIFF` with `EPSG:3857` pseudo-mercator CRS.

   - for example, pick `custom-EPSG-3857.tif` as file name.
3. `Calculate from Layer` the extent, pick `Layer Resolution` for resolution, export.
4. Use `gdal_translate custom-EPSG-3857.tif custom.mbtiles` to convert to `mbtiles` -- should be available in a `virtualenv` with `pip install gdal`.
5. Use `gdaladdo -r nearest custom.mbtiles 2 4 8 16` to add zoom levels if needed -- might be required by `OSMAnd`.
6. Run `git clone "https://github.com/tarwirdur/mbtiles2osmand"`
7. Run `python3 mbtiles2osmand/mbtiles2osmand.py -f custom.mbtiles custom.sqlite`
8. Run `sudo adb push custom.sqlite /sdcard/Android/data/net.osmand/files/tiles/custom.sqlitedb` where you replace `/sdcard/Android/data/net.osmand` by the path of your `OSMAnd` application.
9. After restarting `OSMAnd`, the file should be listed as overlay.

Note that the file `custom.sqlitedb` correspond to a `custom` overlay listed, however a `custom.sqlite` file won't work -- the suffix must be `.sqlitedb`.

Comment: As a complement, some pointed me out https://github.com/ecometrica/gdal2mbtiles that can perform both the `gdal_translate` and `gdaladdo` steps in a more sound way.

Comment: Thanks so much for this